# ¿Como mostrar el mes con GetDate?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola tengo una pequeña duda, no se si sea lo correcto mostrar el nombre del mes de esta forma, mostrándolo desde la consulta, estoy utilizando SQL server 2016, como lo estoy manejando es como lo siguiente:

```
SELECT CONCAT(Day(GetDate()),' DE ',MONTH(GETDATE()),' DEL ',Year(GetDate()))
```

Pero lo que me muestra es lo siguiente:

**`7 DE 3 DEL 2019`**

¿como puedo hacer que me muestre "Marzo en lugar de un 3"? Espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes realizar esto de dos manera, concatenando los valores o utilizando [FORMAT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql):

```
SET LANGUAGE Spanish

SELECT CONCAT(DAY(GETDATE()),' de ',DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()),' del ',YEAR(GETDATE()))

SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'dd \de MMMM \del yyyy')
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias a todos, es lo que estaba buscando

Answer (score 2):

intenta la siguiente manera:

```
SET LANGUAGE Spanish
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) AS 'MesNombre'
```

saludos

Answer (score 2):

Solo necesitas poner lo siguiente

```
 SELECT CONCAT(Day(GetDate()),' DE ',DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) ,' DEL ',Year(GetDate()))
```